# searching specific line of code in the source code of ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Goal

I want to find specific lines of codes in the source code of ThreadPoolExecutor.

When a task is submitted to ThreadPoolExecutor it creates a thread if all other threads in the pool are busy. Can somebody take me to those lines of code in the source code of ThreadPoolExecutor where it is checked that whether all other threads in the pool are busy or not, and if busy then create a new thread else if idle then handover the task to that idle thread?

Answer (score 0):

The source code is available in the [OpenJDK mercurial repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8).  The bit you're interested in looks to be in the `execute()` method, which is here:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#l1318

You're probably better off opening it up in a properly configured IDE, though, so that you can navigate around in the source more easily.